# The reason of using genitive instead of nominative

Tags: grammar

The German translation of *good day* is *Guten Tag*. Why is it not *Guter Tag*?

And when asked

> Wie geht es dir?

can I answer *Ich bin gut* instead of *Mir geht es gut*?

Comment: These are two questions. Please refrain from asking two unrelated questions in one post. Make it two separate questions instead.

Comment: Btw, where is the genitive?

Comment: @c.p. "guten" is both genitive and accusative, so I assume that's the reason for believing it could be genitive.

Comment: @Em1 In dem Fall sollte es aber konsequent "Tag(e)s" anstelle "Tag" da vorkommen, finde ich.

Comment: @c.p. Fair enough. Vielleicht war es auch nur ein Vertipper.

Comment: BTW: the second part is about *Dativ* - so all 4 cases are involved ;)